# Placing center of circles with changing radius at corners of div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a control in leaflet, consisting of an icon, a number and 2 circles, looking something like this:

```
-  -  -  -  -  -  -  
|                 * |
|ICON   3.2         |
|                 * |
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -
```

I want the 2 circles in the right upper and lower corner, to have a fixed center position - but as it is now it is simply the corner of the box (that is used to create the circle), that has a fixed position at the corner of the div.

The circles change radius, and I don't mind if they overlap each other or the border of the div.

CSS:

```
.dot {
    height:10px;
    width: 10px;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width:1px; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
}

div{        
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}

.col1{
    width:20px;
    height:25px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}


.col2{
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.col3{
    width:20px;
    height:25px;
    position: relative;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT/HTML:

```
//set content of control
control_object[d.key].setContent(
'<div class="col1">' +transport_icons[d.key] + '</div>
 <div class="col2"> &nbsp;' + (number_of_itches/time_spent).toFixed(2) + '</div>
 <div class="col3">
     <div class="dot" style="background-color:green; top: 0px; right: 0px; height:' + 2*green_radius + 'px; width:' + 2*green_radius + 'px">
     </div>
     <div class="dot"  style="background-color:red; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; height:' + 2*red_radius + 'px; width:' + 2*red_radius + 'px">
     </div>
  </div>');
```

Comment: You're floating all your divs to the left, so I have a hunch that all the positions, aligns and displays aren't working properly due to the floats. I would advice you to recode the entire CSS using CSS grid since that gives you almost complete pixelperfect control of the position of any element without having to rely on ( imho more complicated ) position/floating/margin combinations.

Comment: Can you post the basic structure of the html you're using? You might be able to get away with centering your circles inside a container and then aligning that container where you want the center to be and then having the circles overflow that container.

Comment: When you say the basic structure of the html do you mean '<div class= ....'  - because that is what I have written inside the setContent function - but maybe I can make it more clear :)

Comment: Is there going to be content going inside these circles? Or are they just purely visual indicators?

Comment: No content inside - it is simply their size that indicates something :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. So here's a css only solution. Although it remains to be seen if it will interface well with your current code. The main fallback is that you probably can't put any html inside the dot or it will break.

The idea is that you have a 0 width and height element (`.dot`) that will be positioned wherever you want the center of your circle to be using the `top, left, bottom, right` css attributes.

You then use the `::after` psuedo element to draw the circle. Since the circle will be drawn at the top left, we have to translate it left and right by 50% to center it.

For ease of use the circle inherits the width and height from the `.dot` element. Since max-width and max-height are set to 0 the `.dot` element will never display, but the width and height can be set to whatever. This means that you can use your current system of setting width and height in the style attribute of the element and it should just work.

The background is also inherited, so it can be set from the `.dot` class as well.

```js
const circles = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.dot'))

function changeSize(width=1, height=1){
  circles.forEach(circle => {
    const cwidth = circle.style.width || 25,
      cheight = circle.style.height || 25
    circle.style.width = (parseInt(cwidth) + width) + "px"
    circle.style.height = (parseInt(cheight) + height) + "px"
  })
}
```

```css
.dot {
  position : absolute;
  background : silver;
  width : 25px;
  height : 25px;
  max-width : 0px;
  max-height : 0px;
}

.dot::after {
  content : "";
  display : block;
  background : inherit;
  transform : translate(-50%, -50%);
  width : inherit;
  height : inherit;
  border-radius : 50%;
}

.container {
  position : relative;
  width : 300px;
  height : 150px;
  background : red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div 
    class="dot"
    style="right : 25px; top: 25px;">
   </div>
  <div 
    class="dot"
    style="right : 25px; bottom: 25px;">
   </div>
</div>
<div>
Width
<button onclick="changeSize(1, 0)">+</button>
<button onClick="changeSize(-1, 0)">-</button>
</div>

<div>
Height
<button onclick="changeSize(0, 1)">+</button>
<button onClick="changeSize(0, -1)">-</button>
</div>

<div>
both
<button onclick="changeSize(1, 1)">+</button>
<button onClick="changeSize(-1, -1)">-</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much - that works perfect for my case :)